# Bootstrap dropdown menu close on click inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have the following code:

```js
function dosomething(id, event){
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
// dosomething
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="toggle">click</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu options_drop pull-right">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dosomething(111,event)">do some thing1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dosomething(111,event)">do some thing2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I use the dropdown dropdown, but when I click on one of the two **Li** tags, the dropdown does not automatically hide.
Please help me solve this problem,

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to hide all li on each click try this:

```js
$("ul li").click(function () {
   $("li").hide("slow")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="toggle">click</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu options_drop pull-right">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">do some thing1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">do some thing2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for support but not But this is not what I need

Comment: So explain whats exaclty u need please